# How does the chain rule work with e in the example here?

Tags: calculus

Use the Chain Rule to find the derivative. 
$$y = e^{13+x^{2}}$$

I know the chain rule, but seeing $e$ kind of throws me off.

Comment: It works the usual way. You should've come across the result that $\frac{d}{du} e^u = e^u$, so
$$\frac{d}{dx} e^{u(x)} = \frac{du}{dx} \frac{ d}{du} e^u$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e^x is a function. Imagine it as f(x).
13+x^2 is also a function imagine is as g(x)

Hence, it is f(g(x)). Now use the chain rule